# List users with custom fields

Tags: users, 8

Is there way to list all users? I haven't found such method on `UserInterface`. The few hints I found on internet are for version 7 or using `entityManager` which is deprecated. Loading custom fields is a bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$users = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::loadMultiple();
$field = $user->get('field_custom_field');
$value = $field->getString();
```